# Angular Material checkbox alignment

Tags: css, angular, checkbox

I have a little alignment problem that I cannot solved.
I am using Angular Material checkbox component for showing list of options and the user can click on them and choose multiple options. Everything is working fine but i am facing a little bit of style issue that i really cannot solve.

[Code Sample on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kbfwff?file=src/app/checkbox-configurable-example.html)

What I want to have at the end is have all the checkboxes aligned at the right of the available space.

[image: Sample image of how i need it to be aligned]

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: An easy way to solve this is to use `mat-selection-list` (without the ripple), where the checkbox is already aligned on the right side: [Example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zmwveb?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist-selection-example.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to solve this is to use Angular Material's `mat-selection-list` ([Angular Material list API reference docs](https://material.angular.io/components/list/api)) and then excluding its ripple effect, where the checkbox is already aligned on the right side.

component.ts

```js
testItems: string[] = ['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3', 'Test 4', 'Test 5'];
```

component.html

```html
<mat-selection-list [disableRipple]="true" #item>
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let test of testItems">
    {{test}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

The benefit of this is that you don't have to deal with default `mat-checkbox` styling and `mat-selection-list` is an Angular component too, resulting in an [example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zmwveb?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist-selection-example.html).

Outcome of StackBlitz:

[image: Outcome of StackBlitz]

Comment: Thank you !
This is what i was looking for!

Comment: @MiteTashkov You're welcome. Please mark the answer as approved so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to your css will work:

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-inner-container {
  margin-right: 0 !important;
```

}

You need to either use !important or increase your selector specificity by adding an id on the checkbox and using it in the selector.